# Silverlight UserControl Unloading

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

Is it possible to somehow know when a UserControl is unloading and take some actions before it happens? I am assuming that the Unloaded even is fired after the control is unloaded.

I have a user control that can be unloaded at any time and I need to be able to run some code before it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Unloaded event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to be notified when a UI element is being unloaded.

Comment: So the unloaded event is fired before the control and its children are unloaded?

Comment: @thecaptain0220 Yes.  It's fired as the control gets unloaded (right after it's removed from the main object tree)

Comment: I'm trying to keep a child of the user control from unloading. I was thinking maybe I could remove it in the Unloaded event and move it to another parent. It seems however that even if I do this the child is still unloaded.

Comment: @thecaptain0220 Yeah - unfortunately, at this point, it's already unloaded.  You might be able to recreate it correctly at this point, though.